# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python

fn.py

```
def who(voice):
    e_who = ''.join(['who'])
    Q = voice.replace(e_who , '').strip()
    wikipedia.set_lang('ru')
    A = wikipedia.search(Q)
    return A
```

cf.py

```
commands = {
             "who": ['кто такой' , 'кто это' , 'найди кто такой']
    }
```

main.py

```
A = who(voice)
    e_who = who(voice)
    if e_who in voice:
        talk(A)
```

как написано в функции who я перевёл список в строку но ошибка

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

остаётся

кто может помочь?
в чем я ошибся ?

Comment: Ничего вы в функции who в строку не прессом, потому что она возвращает список.

Comment: ну e_who жк вроде как в who

Comment: e_who в who не имеет ни малейшего отношения к e_who в main.py.

Comment: а так что сделать?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Из этого кода непонятно, что он должен делать, поэтому непонятно, что тут и как исправлять.

Comment: функция who должна вырезать слово сочетания из списка who 

например : кто такой путин

и оставить только 'путин' а после найти это в википедии и показать

Comment: нужно выбросить имеющися код и начать заново. И не делайте все в разных файлах, а делайте в одном.

Comment: так будет не структурировано

Comment: Ну а сейчас тут можно подумать структура. Чтобы разбивать код на модули, нужно понимать, что делаешь и зачем. А у вас с этим проблемы. Не говоря уже о том,  что разбивать десяток строк на три файла не имеет никакого смысла.